# How to bind in swift from the init function of a View

Tags: swift, swiftui

Not sure how to setup bindings from the init function.

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let url: URL

    @State private var videoPos: Double = 0
    @State private var videoDuration: Double = 0
    @State private var seeking = false

    private var videoView: VideoView

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        self.videoView = VideoView(
            url: self.url,
            videoPos: $videoPos,
            videoDuration: $videoDuration,
            seeking: $seeking
        )
    }

    func togglePlay () {
        self.videoView.play()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            videoView
            Button(action: togglePlay) {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the 3 lines with the '$'.

```
Variable 'self.videoView' used before being initialized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI view have to be used within view builder (ie. initiated in some `body`). So, use instead the following

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let url: URL

    @State private var videoPos: Double = 0
    @State private var videoDuration: Double = 0
    @State private var seeking = false

    private var videoView: VideoView { // << computable property
        VideoView(                     //    will be created in body
            url: self.url,
            videoPos: $videoPos,
            videoDuration: $videoDuration,
            seeking: $seeking
        )
    }

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func togglePlay () {
        self.videoView.play()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            videoView
            Button(action: togglePlay) {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost works.... The issue is any time the body need updates a new `VideoView` is created.

Comment: @Justin808, this is expected SwiftUI behaviour, actually swift behaviour... in the same way as ZStack is created, Button, Text, etc. Just make creation light.

Comment: Then how to I call a method on a view without getting a new view? I want to tell the video to play, not create a whole new video view.

Comment: @Justin808, this is SwiftUI - it is reactive - you don't send methods to views, instead change states and views are refreshed on those changes reacting as needed.

Comment: Its not a state... its a function... to do something.... I want to do an action, not update a parameter

Comment: @Justin808, if you provide code of VideoView I can show how to do that.

Comment: I'll mark it as correct, as it is, its just not what I want. I have to pass the whole AVPlayer around, not just a URL.